# Request tab not shown in an error event for Bugsnag Project

Tags: node.js, express, bugsnag

I have an expressjs server that serves Vue content. Based on the [doc](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/express/#basic-configuration) I have setup the Bugsnag integration by doing the following

```
const Bugsnag = require('@bugsnag/js');
const BugsnagPluginExpress = require('@bugsnag/plugin-express');
const express = require('express');

const bugsnag = Bugsnag.start({
    apiKey: bugsnagApiKey,
    appVersion: build.release_version,
    releaseStage: process.env.WEBSITE_ENV,
    plugins: [BugsnagPluginExpress],
    onError: function (event) {
      event.groupingHash = event.request.path;
    }
});
const app = express()
const middleware = Bugsnag.getPlugin('express')
app.use(middleware.requestHandler)

app.get("*", auth, (req, res) => {
    try {
        html = render()
        res.send(html)
    } catch (e) {
        bugsnag.notify(e);
    }
})
```

but the "Request" tab does not appear for the Bugsnag error event in the Web UI. I am mainly looking for request related data such as url, path, etc. Is there configuration I am missing somewhere?

[image]

Note: The project is setup to be a "Vue" project because it is used as a destination for both client-side and server-side JS errors. Could this be related?